# Place an image over an image in google maps API marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this frame that I am currently using as my marker images https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOh5X.png. I would like the frames to be populated with images that I search for. My code for the marker looks like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: results[i].geometry.location,
    map: map,
    name: results[i].name,
    //icon: eachPhotoinArray
    icon: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOh5X.png'
});
```

Is there a way to get my photos to be placed directly on top of the frame image?

Answer (score 2):

possible approach(using CSS):

markers by default will be rendered via `<canvas>`, to render them as `<img>` set the `optimized`-option of the  marker to `false`

The problem: There is no implemented way to access the `<img>`-elements directly, but when you know the URL of the marker you may use a CSS-selector based on this URL to "insert" the images via background:

```
   img[src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOh5X.png']{
    background:url(http://domain.com/path/to/img.png) no-repeat 4px 4px
   }
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/o6et77jx/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/o6et77jx/)

The problem is clear, you will not be able to load different images into the frame, because the selector is always the same.

Solution:
add e.g. a hash to the URL to get a  distinct selector:

```
   img[src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOh5X.png#1']{
    background:url(http://domain.com/path/to/img.png) no-repeat 4px 4px
   }

   img[src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOh5X.png#2']{
    background:url(http://domain.com/path/to/anotherimg.png) no-repeat 4px 4px
   }
```

These style-rules may be created via script when you want to, see [**http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets**](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets) (Safely Applying Rules)

Demo(using an array with the format`[latitude,longitude,image-url,marker-title]`) :

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/w8z3kg6y/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/w8z3kg6y/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. So are you saying there is no solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: my answer provides a solution