# Issue with z-index of label and image using Google Maps API and MarkerWithLabel

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Ever since I launched http://iknowwhereyourcatlives.com I've never been happy with the way I executed the frame around the icons. The problem is that the frame isn't on the same z-index as the icon picture so the frames overlap other photos.

[image: problem]

To implement the frame I'm using [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/reference.html) and a .png with a hole in it.

I've tried a number of solutions with CSS and hacks with JS to fix this but can't seem figure out why this is happening. What's interesting is that according to the Chrome console the frame is only 1 z-index above the marker image...

[image]

I'm including a code sample below which can be seen live here http://jsfiddle.net/ow3n/uwsL3os9/

```
// display map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
// the image to display inside the marker
var marker_img = {
    url: 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/examples/home.jpg',
    size: new google.maps.Size(76, 76), // mask size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(10, 10), // image anchor
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(35, 88), // mask anchor
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(95, 95) // image size
};
// marker positions
var positions = [
    [49.45805, -123.84716],
    [49.46805, -123.85716],
    [49.47805, -123.86716]
];
// place markers on map with MarkerWithLabel
for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    var pictureLabel = document.createElement("img");
    pictureLabel.src = "http://iknowwhereyourcatlives.com/assets/img/frame.png";
    var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(positions[i][0], positions[i][4]);
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: homeLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: marker_img,
        draggable: false,
        labelContent: pictureLabel,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(40, 98), // x,y
        labelClass: "labels label"+i, // the CSS class for the label
        labelStyle: {
            opacity: 1
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You compare the zIndex  of the wrong elements. Take a look at the opacity, it's set to 0.01, these elements are  overlayMouseTargets, which receive the mouse-events, but are not visible. I'm afraid the MarkerWithLabel-library is not the right tool to achieve it. A much easier solution: a simple Marker(the frame) with a background(the cats). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707155/place-an-image-over-an-image-in-google-maps-api-marker/25708388#25708388

Comment: An easier *and better* solution. Thanks so much. Here's a fork of the fiddle with the fix http://jsfiddle.net/ow3n/m84s0xr4/1/ - updating site now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Dr.Molle thanks again for your help. Site updated: http://iknowwhereyourcatlives.com/ if you would like to post this as an answer I would happily mark it as the solution because as far as I know not using MarkerWithLabel is the only fix.