# How round and resize photo and set it into custom marker of Google Map API V3

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3, polymer

i want to create custom map marker for Google Map by combining two images `marker_bg` and `marker_pic` how i can do. `Marker_bg` will marker with empty space inside which will fill by `marker_pic`.

Round pic and set it into marker?

[image]

i'm using following technologies;

- HTML5/JAVASCRIPT/CSS3
- Polymer#0.5
- Google Map API V3
- PHP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707155/place-an-image-over-an-image-in-google-maps-api-marker/25708388#25708388

Comment: thanks Dr.Molle but what will be the affect of setting optimized: false? This will reduce image quality or its performance?

Comment: Something like this ?? **https://www.upsieutoc.com/image/ps9v**

Comment: It may reduce the map-performance while panning, zooming etc. when you have a lot of markers

Comment: still have no solution @Dr.Molle your solution is good but what about to round and resize image?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: MAP_INSTANCE,
    position: LOCAIOTN,
    visible: true,
    icon: ICON_PATH
});
```

use SVG icon and change inside image path to user image path.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image width="80" height="80"
     xlink:href="[USER_ICON_PATH]" />
</svg>
```

PHP to generate different SVG for different users.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/';
echo '<svg width="216" height="216">
    <defs>
        <rect id="rect" x="8" y="8"width="200" height="200" rx="50%"/>
        <clipPath id="clip">
          <use xlink:href="#rect"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#rect" stroke-width="8" stroke="black"/>
    <image xlink:href="' . $url . '"  width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>';
?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhkxxh90/43/

UPDATE: added php example

UPDATE: added jsfiddle links to anwser

Comment: @JohnDev you can so something like this http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/bhkxxh90/1/

Comment: you can add multiple images in SVG, see this example  http://jsfiddle.net/bhkxxh90/8/

Comment: i created it in svg see this http://jsfiddle.net/bhkxxh90/13/ it is displaying in jsfiddle perfect but when i use it in html5 its not displaying correctly image and marker have space between them.

Comment: can you share screenshot of that ?

Comment: That's exactly why this solution doesn't work at all. I don't understand the upvotes. <img src='svg.svg'> is what it finally be for a maps marker. This will work with simple svg, but if it has more complex stuff in it (as xlink:href) it will not work.

Comment: Same. Try sourcing this valid svg in an image. <img src='your.svg'>

Comment: Question needs dynamic image per user so we need to generate svg per person. You can use <img src=“some_path/{{user_id}}.svg”/>. And i have above explained the way to generate that in PHP and also how u can combine that with google maps

Comment: Actually, try it already! Sourced svg's must be self-contained. Meaning must not have external links as xlink:href. As said, your svg is valid as long as it is not used as a source of an image.

Answer (score 0):

If You have this. I thing you can try add 2 layer of marker,
Layer 1 is picture 1, and it is png image no background, layer 2 is picture 2 with avata image, and 2 layer is 1 location or you can change location if it not match or not beauty :)

> like this **https://www.upsieutoc.com/image/ps9v**

code

```
function setMarker(avataUrl, location){
(function(avataUrl,location){
    var layer1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    location: location,
                    icon : 'url image layer 1'
                });
    var layer2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    location: location,
                    icon : avataUrl
                }); 
})(avataUrl,location);
}
```

Comment: That is not a good advice. When you use marker clusterer this will double all your marker counts. Also, you will have to double click events, info windows, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Atleast i have done it. Thanks @jad-panda for your help from which i am able to create this you didn't understand what i want but i created it by using your code here is complete code:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhkxxh90/9/)

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
        <rect id="rect" x="10%" width="80%" height="80%" rx="50%"/>
        <clipPath id="clip">
          <use xlink:href="#rect"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#rect"/>
    <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"  width="80%" height="80%" x="10%" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
    <image xlink:href="http://i61.tinypic.com/5zk09e.png"  width="100%" height="100%"/>

</svg>
```

Image Positions are set according to frame if frame change then maybe x and y of image also need to change.

Comment: You have created an svg that sources and clips an image. You have not been able to accomplish what OP asks for: source the svg in an image while maintaining the image links.